# Extracting text from a paragraph between two symbols in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a paragraph of text and I would like to extract every sample size from it.  I usually can get Regex to work, but I am unable to.

Here is an example:

```
x = "OBJECTIVES:

In diabetic polyneuropathy (DPN) patients, the effect of folic acid and homocysteine has been related to components of nerve conduction velocity (NCV). The objective of this study was to determine the effect of folic acid supplementation on NCV in DPN patients.
METHODS:

Patients were randomized to receive either 1 mg of folic acid (n = 40) or placebo (n = 40) for 16 weeks. Blood samples were collected to assess serum folic acid and homocysteine concentrations, and NCV was performed for assessment of diabetic neuropathy.
RESULTS:

At 16 weeks, in the supplemented group, serum levels of folic acid (p < 0.001) increased, homocysteine concentrations decreased (p < 0.001), with no change in serum vitamin B12 levels. There was a significant increase in sensory sural amplitude (p < 0.001), and components of motor nerves, including amplitude (p = 0.001) and velocity (p < 0.001), but decreased onset latency of peroneal (p = 0.019) and tibial (p = 0.011) motor nerves.
CONCLUSION:

Our data suggest that supplementation with 1 mg of folic acid for 16 weeks may be useful for enhancing NCV in DPN patients."
```

I would like to extract out the two sample sizes.  In this case n = 40 and n = 40.

I have tried

```
gsub('.*[n=]|).*','',x)
```

I get back `ts.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `stringr` to extract "n = " followed by at least one digit. This assumes there will be no-space or one space either side of the equal sign:

```
library(stringr)
str_extract_all(x, "n\\s?\\=\\s?\\d+")
[[1]]
[1] "n = 40" "n = 40"
```

EDIT: The following should work inside `mutate` with your other condition. I switched from `stringr` to `stringi` to get `NA` for a string with no matches. Also, you could use `paste` instead of `stri_flatten` but I would stick with `stri_flatten` because it retains `NA` as a missing value and not a character `"NA"` like `paste` does.

```
sapply(stri_extract_all(x, regex = "n\\s?\\=\\s?\\d+"), stri_flatten, collapse = ", ")
```

For regex I started with [this cheat sheet](https://www.rstudio.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/RegExCheatsheet.pdf) for R (and still reference it). The above regex works like so:

`n` - the letter n

`\\s?` - at most 1(the `?`) space(`\\s`) (you may prefer MrFlick's use of `*` over the `?`--your call)

`\\=` - equal sign

`\\s?` - at most 1(the `?`) space(`\\s`)

`\\d+` - one or more(`+`) digits(`\\d`)

**Data**:

```
x = c("OBJECTIVES:

In diabetic polyneuropathy (DPN) patients, the effect of folic acid and homocysteine has been related to components of nerve conduction velocity (NCV). The objective of this study was to determine the effect of folic acid supplementation on NCV in DPN patients.
METHODS:

Patients were randomized to receive either 1 mg of folic acid (n = 40) or placebo (n = 40) for 16 weeks. Blood samples were collected to assess serum folic acid and homocysteine concentrations, and NCV was performed for assessment of diabetic neuropathy.
RESULTS:

At 16 weeks, in the supplemented group, serum levels of folic acid (p < 0.001) increased, homocysteine concentrations decreased (p < 0.001), with no change in serum vitamin B12 levels. There was a significant increase in sensory sural amplitude (p < 0.001), and components of motor nerves, including amplitude (p = 0.001) and velocity (p < 0.001), but decreased onset latency of peroneal (p = 0.019) and tibial (p = 0.011) motor nerves.
CONCLUSION:

Our data suggest that supplementation with 1 mg of folic acid for 16 weeks may be useful for enhancing NCV in DPN patients.", "no numbers here", "n = 100")
```

Comment: How could I use this inside of a mutate to add a single column with `n = 40, n = 40` and have an `NA` if the list is empty for some rows?  Also is there  a link that explains the regex commands you used?

Comment: Hey @BryanAdams, I updated the answer. Let me know if you run into any issues!

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to extract those values

```
regmatches(x, gregexpr('n\\s*=\\s*\\d+',x))
```

here we look for n= (with possible spaces around the equals sign) and then extract those with the `regmatches`.

Answer (score 1):

An ugly solution without regex could be:

```
#first "n = "
substr(strsplit(x, "n = ",fixed=T)[[1]][2],1,2)
#second "n = "
substr(strsplit(x, "n = ",fixed=T)[[1]][3],1,2)
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to retrive the number between parenthesis is like this:

```
library(stringr)

lapply(str_split(x,pattern="\\("),function(x) gsub('(.*)\\).*','\\1',x))
[[1]]
 [1] "OBJECTIVES:\n\nIn diabetic polyneuropathy "
 [2] "DPN"                                       
 [3] "NCV"                                       
 [4] "n = 40"                                    
 [5] "n = 40"                                    
 [6] "p < 0.001"                                 
 [7] "p < 0.001"                                 
 [8] "p < 0.001"                                 
 [9] "p = 0.001"                                 
[10] "p < 0.001"                                 
[11] "p = 0.019"                                 
[12] "p = 0.011"
```

You split the text using \( as a pattern and apply the gsub in each piece of it.
Afterwards you can use grep to identify which elements start with "n =" to retrieve the one you need.

I hope it helps